# derivative of log-lambert function

Tags: derivatives, lambert-w

How can I calculate the derivative of the following function w.r.t $x$

$$f(x)=\log_2(1+W(ax))$$

where $W$ is the lambert function.

Comment: Hint: chain rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\log_2(1+W(ax))=\frac{\log (1+W(a x))}{\log (2)}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{\log (2)}\, \frac{W'(ax)}{1+W(a x)}$$
Since $$W'(t)=\frac{W(t)}{t (1+W(t))}$$ then $f'(x)=\cdots \,\,???$